# Is there a JavaScript or jQuery equivalent to Python's "sum" built-in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

Say I have an array-ish container of decimal numbers. I want the sum. In Python I would do this:

```
x = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]

sum(x)
```

Is there a similarly concise way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another approach, a simple iterative function:

```
function sum(arr) {
  var result = 0, n = arr.length || 0; //may use >>> 0 to ensure length is Uint32
  while(n--) {
    result += +arr[n]; // unary operator to ensure ToNumber conversion
  }
  return result;
}

var x = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6];
sum(x); // 10.2
```

Yet another approach using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var arr = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6];
arr.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0); // 10.2
```

The `reduce` method is part of the ECMAScript 5th Edition standard, is widely available,  but is not on IE <= 8, however an implementation cay be included from the the Mozilla Dev Center I linked.

Answer (score 7):

I guess there's none... but you can make one on javascript

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
  return (! this.length) ? 0 : this.slice(1).sum() +
      ((typeof this[0] == 'number') ? this[0] : 0);
};
```

use it as,

```
[1,2,3,4,5].sum() //--> returns 15
[1,2,'',3,''].sum() //--> returns 6
[].sum() //--> returns 0    
x = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
x.sum(); // returns 10.2
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq3jN/)

---

Okay as pointed out in the comment, you can also do it as non-recursive way

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() {
   var num = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       num += (typeof this[i] == 'number') ? this[i] : 0;
   }
   return num;
};
```

---

Another way to do it, through function..

```
function sum(arr) {
   var num = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       num += (typeof arr[i] == 'number') ? arr[i] : 0;
   }
   return num;
};
```

use it as,

```
sum([1,2,3,4,5]) //--> returns 15
x = [1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
sum(x); // returns 10.2
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, wouldn't this recursive implementation easily hit the stack limit? Any reason not to use an iterative solution with a for loop?

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Please do not go modifying object prototypes. I've run into serious issues with this kind of nonsense. Write a $.sum jQuery plugin, and don't screw the rest of us.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall can you give me something to read or any for that matter? `modifying object prototypes`... ;)

Comment: @Stefan, wish I could +1000 you -- the ability to modify built-ins is one detail I classify as a defect in JS (and Ruby) and it has never given me anything but trouble (esp. in JS as I don't use Ruby much;-).

Comment: @Reigel: Give a look to [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Comment: @CMS, thanks for the link... @Stefan, could you do the honor to edit my function above as `$.sum`?

Comment: Writing static jQuery plugin methods is literally trivial. Stick `$.sum =` in front of your function, and you have a jQuery plugin :P

Comment: @Reigel: You're welcome, BTW the [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/slice) method call on your recursive approach can be *really* expensive, because `slice` will generate a new array object each time is invoked.